Biber stops working after updating Textlive [Arch]
Since the latest update from texlive I am not able to render my cites anymore.
pdflatex works but calling biber does nothing than showing me this error/info message:
Can't locate PAR.pm in @INC (you may need to install the PAR module) (@INC entries checked: /usr/local/perl/lib/site_perl/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/local/perl/lib/site_perl/5.38.2 /usr/local/perl/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/local/perl/lib/5.38.2) at -e line 612.
Can't locate File/Temp.pm in @INC (you may need to install the File::Temp module) (@INC entries checked: /usr/local/perl/lib/site_perl/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/local/perl/lib/site_perl/5.38.2 /usr/local/perl/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/local/perl/lib/5.38.2) at -e line 30.
END failed--call queue aborted.

This is the output from biber --verison.
I also tried to reinstall biber and also do a rollback from the update, but nothing resolved the issue.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

see https://forum.manjaro.org/t/biber-issue-cant-locate-par-pm-in-inc/35629/2 or https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/221 so that was a temporary issue around 2018/2019 what texlive have you installed?

I tried it but had no success. This is my texlive verison
TeX 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2024) kpathsea version 6.4.0

I’m voting to close this question because the OP answered, it was solved somehow …

I got it working now. I don't know why, but simply removed texlive-full and biber did the job for me.
After setting the PATH back again to 2023 my pdftex works again and after removing biber I resolved the incompatibility issue of biber and bibtex.
